# Can't insert video into timeline in Premiere Pro?

Tags: video-editing, adobe-premiere

I am using Premiere Pro CS5 and I edited a video in After Effects CS6, rendered it as a `.avi` file, imported the `.avi` file into Premiere Pro and that worked. I then placed the video into the source area and then set an end and start point.

However when I click 'Insert', it doesn't insert into the timeline. The Insert button is not greyed out, I can click it but it doesn't insert anything. Am I doing something wrong? Am I supposed to highlight what I want inserted or something?

This is my first time using it and did exactly what the person in this tutorial did except it is not inserting for me for some reason.

Here is the video I was following (probably won't help you guys)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRCWV5PJAJk

Note: it is also not allowing me to drag the video straight into the timeline, or drag the video from the source section to the timeline.

#### Update

If you look at the video provided and pause and 2:18, in his timeline, it says 'Video 1' 'Video 2' and 'Video 3'.. for me, there is nothing, it is just blank, and the time 00;00;00;00 is just greyed out for me while for him it is yellow. For him it says 'sequence 01' but for me it says 'no sequences'.. how do I put a sequence in there? There was a sequence automatically created when I started the project but I can't drag it to the timeline for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. I just needed to double click the sequence, dragging it wasn't working for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

If you're stumbling across this as I did with Premiere Pro Creative Cloud and the solution given by user2719875 doesn't fix it, Then you may be able to fix it by ensuring that at least one video and audio track is selected.

So for example, in the image below, you'll note I have V1, V2, and V3 (and the same for audio):

[image: Unselected tracks on a sequence]

All of them are unselected. It doesn't seem to matter on an empty sequence as in the example, but when you have multiple audio and video files already on the sequence, if you try and click and drag another on there, Premiere doesn't know where it can safely place it without stuffing something up or moving something out of place.

By clicking on the V1, V2 etc names, you can 'select' one or multiple of them to allow drag-n-drop:

[image: Selected tracks]

In this example I have selected the V1 and A1 tracks, and this will allow me to drag the clip onto the timeline.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: @emrah - Glad I could help :)

Comment: I did not need it. Just pointing out. Can you tell if this is changed after CC. Because CS6 doesn't act like that and Adobe staff says something about decoupling.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only confirm the version that I have a license for which is CC, I don't know what the behavior is like in CS6

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers mentioned here worked for me.

If you can't drag & drop video in the timeline, you have to create a sequence. 
So, navigate to
“File” → “New” → “Sequence”
or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in Windows, and then click “Ok”.

Now, try dragging the video into the timeline.

If the media info you just selected didn't match with your video's metadata then you'll get a prompt for the adjustment based on your video's original media info when you drag & drop the video in the timeline. Do whatever suits you.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that recently, and what fixed it for me was literally clicking on the "V" to the left of the lock icon to "activate that track" when it was not selected (and turned blue) I could not drop a track on the timeline.